DrawArrayInstanced is not rendering what it should (OPENGL)
GLfloat triangle_vertices1[6] = {
    -0.6f, 0.2f,
    -0.3f, 0.2f,
    -0.3f, 0.5f
};

GLfloat triangle_vertices2[6] = {
    0.6f, 0.2f,
    0.3f, 0.2f,
    0.3f, 0.5f
};

GLfloat triangle_colorsInstanced[6] = {
    0.8, 0.2, 0.1,
    0.1, 0.2, 0.8
};

    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[2]);
    glGenBuffers(3, Buffers);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangle_vertices1) + sizeof(triangle_vertices2), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(triangle_vertices1), triangle_vertices1);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangle_vertices1), sizeof(triangle_vertices2), triangle_vertices2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[2]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangle_colorsInstanced), triangle_colorsInstanced, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribDivisor(1, 1);
    glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3, 2);


This is the code, it generates one triangle (first one in the vbo), and the its the second color in the vbo!

Well, what should it do? You gotta tell us. Right now it does indeed draw the first triangle in the VBO, but it draws it twice, once with the first colour and once with the second one (likely the second one gets drawn on top of the first one and that's why you see the second colour). That's exactly what you tell it to do, though. Your glDrawArraysInstanced call says "draw me the first 3 points in the VBO at attrib 0, but draw them twice, once with the first colour in the VBO at attrib 1 and then with the second one". Is there a chance you're confused what instancing actually does?
